# calling javascript methods from an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem with my Javascript.

i have got a form to upload an image where the target is an iframe

```
<form ... target="uploadframe">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
</form>
<iframe name="uploadframe" ></iframe>
```

the form works fine. but i want to call two javascript function when the server is ready?

my functions are inside an jquery onload event

```
$(function(){
    function myFunction(){...}
});
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the functions to the window object and call it from inside the iframe.

```
$(function(){
    window.myFunction = function myFunction(){...};
});
```